# How do I enhance third party npm modules to submit PRs on github while working on my application

Tags: node.js, git, github

I would say I am still a beginner with using git and developing web applications. I have come across this issue a couple of times now and wanted to ask the community what is the preferred way of solving it. The issue is that let's say I am working on a web application `MyWebApp` which imports a few npm modules. Let's say it is using a third party npm module `Module1`. Now, I need a couple of features in `Module1` which are not there right now, so I want to add those features myself and submit a PR once I am done. Now, usually `node_modules` directory is included in the `.gitignore` file, so git doesn't keep track of changes that I made directly under node_modules directory. Moreover, I need to fork a repo from original `Module1` repo to be able to submit a PR. So, I do that and update my `package.json` to say `Module1: "username/Module1` and clone the forked repo in a separate directory and start add to features over there which I will get when I do `npm update Module1`. Here is where the problem lies. Since adding a new feature is an iterative process, it is pretty big round trip time to add something in the cloned repo, push the changes and then run `npm update Module1` only to find that you missed one more small thing and the whole thing starts again.

How do people get around this problem? Do they clone the repo for forked `Module1` in the `node_modules` directory itself within the web app? I am not sure if that will work. Please share your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how npm works exactly, some packagemanagers just clone repositories the same as you would, so `node_modules/some_module` might be a git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this question because it's an inversion to a normal problem wherein people are trying to use git subtrees as a project dependency and never backporting commits to the subtree. In their case, they should be using a package manager like npm. You have the opposite scenario. Instead of including these packages as a dependency, you should graft them into your parent project repository as a subtree. Then you can easily Google the steps for backporting commits to the subtree repository of your package clone, and finally open a pull request to the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for response. It has pointed me to look in the right direction. This gist sums up the workflow and the commands to use pretty well https://gist.github.com/kvnsmth/4688345